# Excel - How to not save cells or worksheets in new files

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, office365, save-as

I'm wondering if it's possible to not save some cells or even worksheets on new file using a model.

To explain better: I have a excel model that I use to save data in new files. Now to automatize some task I would like to some use some cells in my model for this purpose. Then when I will save the file those cells **should not be present** (not hidden but removed completely), and the cells that refer to those cells **should contain only the values and not the formula referencing those cell**. It's possible to do this maybe avoiding macros.

I'm using office 365.

Comment: With macros, it seems not too hard. Without macros, you could manually do what the macro would need to do; probably no other way.

Comment: Without VBA (Macro), you need to Move that particular Worksheet into other Workbook and then save rest, in this way you could skip those Cells to save.

Comment: You may use Auto Filter method to Filter & delete those rows before save the file using MACRO.